# Where should I place this if statement so that it executes when each of the buttons is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, function

I am programming a Rock Paper Scissors windows forms game with an option to play against the computer or another player using the keyboard arrows.
The form is not yet finished, since it will have some pictures on the pictures boxes according to the user's play.

When checkbox1 is checked it looks like this:
[image]

When checkbox2 is checked it looks like this:

[image]

I have already written functions `computer_choice` and `Check_Winner` which return the random computer choice and winner of each round, respectively.
And when someone clicks on the button with the option, choice1 is set to the option the button corresponds to.
Then I wrote this code put I don't know where to place it. Because I want the program to present the winner and each of the choices only when both players have played. Basically I want a practical way for this to execute when one of the icons on the screen has been clicked and the player two has pressed one of the arrows as well. Basically when `choice1` and `choice2` are both different than null and equal to one of the three choices. I have already wrote something like `choice1 = "Rock";` on the Rock_click function.
In addition, I want to know if it's a good idea to add this function to class1 and if so, how should I do it so that I can use the form1 variables.

I wrote something like this but I don't know how to use it so that it takes into consideration the events I just mentioned.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && choice1 != null)
{
    string choice2 = class1.computer_choice();

    MessageBox.Show("Winner is " + class1.Check_Winner(choice1, chocie2);
    MessageBox.Show("Player one chose " + choice1 + " and computer chose " + choice2);
    choice1= null;
}
else if (checkBox2.Checked && choice2 != null && choice1 != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Winner is " + class1.Check_Winner(choice1, choice2 ));
    MessageBox.Show("Player one chose " + choice1+ "and player two chose " + choice2);
    choice1 = choice2 null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! I saw you separated your concerns: you had separate procedures to play to let the computer choose a value and to decide the winner.

Now all you have to do is to separate also your inputs and your outputs.

The operator has three buttons to press. Configure your Form such, that when any of these three buttons is pressed the following function is called:

```
bool IsTwoPlayerGame => return this.CheckBoxTwoPlayers.Checked;

void OnPlayButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // operator pressed one of the playButtons. Which button is in the sender
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, buttonRock))
       Play(Choice.Rock);
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, buttonPaper))
       Play(Choice.Paper);
    else
       Play(Choice.Scissors);
}
```

Apparently we need function Play, with a parameter that says what this Played. The function has to wait for the other Player to make a choice (whether it is a human or a computer does not matter). Once the other Player made a choice we check the winner:

```
void Play(Choice thisPlayersChoice)
{
    var otherPlayersCoice = this.FetchOtherPlayersChoice();
    var winner = this.CheckWinner(thisPlayersChoice, otherPlayersChoice);
    DislayWinner(thisPlayersChoice, otherPlayersChoice, winner);
}

Choice FetchOtherPlayersChoice()
{
    return this.IsTwoPlayerGame ??
       this.OtherPlayersChoice() :
       this.ComputerChoice();
}

void Display(Choice choice1, Choice choice2, Winner winner)
{
    string displayText = this.IsTwoPlayerGame ?
        $"Player 1 chose {choice1}, Player 2 chose {choice2}. Winner: {winner}" :
        $"Player 1 chose {choice1}, Computer chose {choice2}. Winner: {winner}";
    MessageBox.Show(displayText);
}
```

Because you separated the concerns, your procedures aren't mangled with all kinds of in and output. For instance: an improvement would be to change your two check boxes with two radio buttons, so it is always clear whether we have a one-player game or a two player game. Changes in your code will be minimal. Also if you decide to have only one check box that says "play against computer"

By the way, you will have a problem if the other player takes some time to answer his question: your window can't update in the mean time. But that question is a complete new one

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was really helpful! I'm sorry but I just don't understand the `Choice` part, what is it exactly? Is it like an array with the choices? Because it's undefined for me.

Comment: Identifier Choice is the name of an enum I used. Whenever you have a limited number of values that a variable can take, you usually define an enum. This makes the code more readable and more robust than if you used values like 1 (meaning paper); 2 (meaning scissors) etc . With an enum you can't assign a value that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use checkboxes because it is either player vs ai or player vs player, it cannot be both. Instead, try [`RadioButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Anyways, the code you have written is fine, you just simply have to call it from each of the 6 buttons' click events. If all 6 events call a single method with these `if` statements, you should be good.